# Applying style to all elements with a name is failing

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to apply styles to all elements with name "Phone".
Applying individually works fine.

```
var input = document.getElementsByName("Phone")[0];
input.style.border = '1px solid #1D0F9D';
input.style.borderRadius = '18px';
input.style.width = '100%';
input.style.height = '30px';
input.style.paddingLeft = '50px';
input.style.paddingTop = '18px';
input.style.paddingBottom = '18px';
input.style.color = '#1D0F9D';
input.style.fontSize = '14px';
input.style.color = 'black';
input.style.outline = '0px solid #26B6D4';
```

This renders the input correctly: 1. Flag drop down 2. input field
[image]

But looping over all the elements does not render the flag drop down:
Similarly setting styles for class phone fails to render it correctly

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("Phone");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].style.border = '1px solid #1D0F9D';
    inputs[i].style.borderRadius = '18px';
    inputs[i].style.width = '100%';
    inputs[i].style.height = '30px';
    inputs[i].style.paddingLeft = '50px';
    inputs[i].style.paddingTop = '18px';
    inputs[i].style.paddingBottom = '18px';
    inputs[i].style.color = '#1D0F9D';
    inputs[i].style.fontSize = '14px';
    inputs[i].style.color = 'black';
    inputs[i].style.outline = '0px solid #26B6D4';
}
```

[image]

Code here :
https://jsfiddle.net/hzorum8x/

Probably missing something very basic. what is it?

Comment: In your jsfiddle there is only 1 input element.

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. In the JSFiddle there’s also other stuff that references `input`. Did you forget to adjust this code?

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you don't even need javascript in your case.

You've got `class="phone"` on the `<input>`, so you can use the class you defined in the `<style>` section, instead of trying to target the `name` attribute. Your code should look something like this:

```
<style>
    .iti {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .phone {
      border: 1px solid #1D0F9D;
      border-radius: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      padding-left: 50px;
      padding-top: 18px;
      padding-bottom: 18px;
      color: #1D0F9D;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
</style>
```

I've also noticed that you defined `color` twice, and gave a `0px solid #26B6D4` outline, which will essentially not display, so I removed these two lines.

Comment: Yeah, this should work, but it does not render the flag drop down. Updated the question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would also like this design to be applied to the dropdown elements, not in the first one only. In this case, you have to target the `li` elements with class `iti__country`. So in other words, add the same style rules of `.phone` to the class `iti__country`, and adjust the paddings accordingly. To make the dropdown cover the whole screen horizontally, add `width: 100%;` to both `iti__flag-container` and `iti__country-list`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only aim to change the style of the elements, using CSS would be simpler

However, the following sample code will hopefully help you

```html
<input name="phone" />
<input name="phone" />
<script>
  addEventListener('load', () => {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('phone');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#abcdef';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Setting event-related properties like `onload` is a pretty outdated way of binding events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Note that there are [much better alternatives](/q/14028959/4642212) to a `load` listener like `defer` or `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, thanks for the remark. I do not disagree. However, (1) I do  not believe this is relevant when it comes to answer this specific answer, (2) the first link in your comment refers to inline event handlers, which are not in use in my sample code, and (3) MDN itself still includes this approach in the `load` event  documentation (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: Then here’re the docs for [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which say at the top _“**Note:** The `addEventListener` method is the_ recommended _way to register an event listener.”_.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the `addEventListener` method as per the recommendation